# nested queries - inner query loop ends outer query loop

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have 2 queries that loop through their recordsets to give output from the inner loop. The outer query loop has several records and the inner query should fire for each record. I'm only getting the first recoed of the outer query loop once the inner loop runs.

I have tried naming $result for the inner query to $result2 and get the error: sqlsrv_fetch_array(): supplied resource is not a valid ss_sqlsrv_stmt resource.

```
// outer loop
$serverName = "livedata";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"ParishHomilyArchive", "UID"=>"ParishUser", "PWD"=>"P@\$\$word" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['Par_Num'])){
    $PN = $_REQUEST['Par_Num'];
}
else{
    $PN = 0;
}

$sql="SELECT Staff.StaffID, Staff.Name, Staff.Photo,     Staff_Position.StaffPage_ID, StaffPages.StaffPageName FROM parishStaff.dbo.StaffPages RIGHT JOIN (ParishStaff.dbo.Staff_Position RIGHT JOIN ParishStaff.dbo.Staff ON Staff_Position.Staff_ID = Staff.StaffID) ON StaffPages.StaffPageID = Staff_Position.StaffPage_ID WHERE (((Staff.par_Num)=" . $PN . ")) ORDER BY Staff.Name, StaffPages.StaffPageName;";



$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {

    //output outer loop stuff



    //inner loop
    $serverName = "livedata";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"database", "UID"=>"User", "PWD"=>"password" );
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conn === false ) {
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['Par_Num'])){
        $PN = $_REQUEST['Par_Num'];
    }
    else{
        $PN = 0;
    }

    $sql2="SELECT StaffPages.StaffPageID, StaffPages.StaffPageName FROM parishStaff.dbo.ParishPages INNER JOIN ParishStaff.dbo.StaffPages ON ParishPages.StaffPage_ID = StaffPages.StaffPageID WHERE (((ParishPages.Par_Num)=" . $PN . ") AND (Not (StaffPages.StaffPageID)=(SELECT StaffPages.StaffPageID FROM ParishStaff.dbo.StaffPages LEFT JOIN (ParishStaff.dbo.Staff_Position LEFT JOIN ParishStaff.dbo.Staff ON Staff_Position.Staff_ID = Staff.StaffID) ON StaffPages.StaffPageID = Staff_Position.StaffPage_ID WHERE (((Staff.StaffID)=" . $row['StaffID']. " )))));"; 

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql2);
    if( $stmt2 === false ) {
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);

    while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {

        //output inner loop stuff

    }



}
```

I want the outer loop to not end after first iteration of inner loop.

Comment: You desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. Your code here is wide open to sql injection. Check out my friend [bobby tables](https://bobby-tables.com/). He explains how dangerous this is and how to fix it.

Comment: I agree with @SeanLange but besides from that you are using same variable ($result) in both inner and outerloop which is problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To answer your question** I rearranged your code a little and set different variables on outerloop resultset and innerloop resultset. I also removed code that were not actually useful for anything like:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql2);
if( $stmt2 === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);
```

Above creates a resultset in `$stmt` and then creates a resultset in `$result`. There's only need for one call to the sqlserver here.

```
<?php
//This is BEFORE loop.. Just need to connect once
$serverName = "livedata";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbname", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"password" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['Par_Num'])){
    $PN = $_REQUEST['Par_Num'];
}
else{
    $PN = 0;
}

$sql="{your SQL-statement}";
$result_outerloop = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if( $result_outerloop === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_outerloop)) {

    $sql2="{your SQL-statement}"; 
    $result_innerresult = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2); //Not same variable as $result_outerloop
    if( $result_innerresult === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_innerresult)) {
        //output inner loop stuff
    }

}
```

But as @Sean Lange points out the SQL itself are not good practice at all. Please read up on parameterized queries. It's actually much easier than doing the way you are doing it.

Comment: i'm getting an error when subquery returns multiple rows: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.  I'm expecting multiple rows for some results in the main query.

Comment: I Finally fixed the problem. The subquery loop was looking at office staff members and finding the offices that the staff member was not a part of. I did this by first querying a list of all offices with the Office_ID. I then filtered the office list with a subquery of the pages that the staff member is linked to. When referencing the subquery i used not equal ( <> ) instead i needed to use ( not in). This got around the subquery returning multiple items error.